# Issue with fetch: Getting type error failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a post call to the backend server, but I keep running into this error:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

I've looked over the code a bunch of times but can't seem to find the issue. Here is the code:

```
 async doLogin() {
        if(!this.state.email || !this.state.password) {
            return
        }
        this.setState({
            buttonDisabled : true
        })
        try {
            let res = await fetch('/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                })
            })
            console.log(res)
            let result = await res.json()
            console.log(result)
            if(result && result.success) {
                UserStores.isLoggedIn = true
                UserStores.email = result.email
                alert(result.msg)
            } else if(result && result.success === false) {
                this.resetForm()
                alert(result.msg)
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('doLogin error: ', e)
            this.resetForm()
        }
    }
```

This is an example response payload:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "email": "mfultz956@gmail.com",
    "msg": "Login Verified!"
}
```

[image: Login Call - Network Tab]

[image: Login Call - Headers]

Comment: do you get this error as an API response or it is from front side?

Comment: I would inspect the HTTP request in the browser developper tool to see if the request is logged. Check the status code, response payload if that's the case...

Comment: @DishantDesai it is from the frontside. I know the backend side is working fine because I've been able to make successful calls using postman.

Comment: do you run your APIs on localhost?

Comment: @DishantDesai yes

Comment: @DavidWilfred does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @DavidWilfredon which port your API server is running?

Comment: @DishantDesai Port 3000

Comment: can you change your API server port to other port because maybe your react APP is also running on port 3000 so that's why it has problme

Comment: @DavidWilfred are you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @DishantDesai the react app is being run as a build on the backend server

Comment: @DavidWilfred have you tried running react app in localhost? you got this error in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

change it to :

```
let res = await fetch('http://localhost:your_api_server_port/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                })
            })
```

Comment: One of these may be possible causes of "network error":

-DNS problems
-the server at url is unavailable/erroneous
-Erroneous HTTP Headers causing the server to ignore the request
-Browser aborted -- most likely due to navigation to another page before the fetch completes